# Dart final functions

Tags: dart

Is it possible for the `_distance` variable to be final but still keep the type signatures in the constructor for a Dart object?

```
Function _distance;

ExampleConstuctor(num distanceFunction(T a, T b)) {
  _distance = distanceFunction;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `1.24.0`, we are introducing a new syntax to do exactly this:

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#language-1

```
typedef F = void Function();  // F is the name for a `void` callback.
int Function(int) f;  // A field `f` that contains an int->int function.

class A<T> {
  // The parameter `callback` is a function that takes a `T` and returns
  // `void`.
  void forEach(void Function(T) callback);
}

// The new function type supports generic arguments.
typedef Invoker = T Function<T>(T Function() callback);
```

Until then you could also use various typedefs declared in `package:func`:

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/func

Comment: Can you provide an example for the OP code, using the new syntax?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a typedef:

```
typedef num DistanceFunction<T>(T a, T b);

class ExampleConstructor<T> {
  final DistanceFunction<T> _distance;

  ExampleConstructor(this._distance);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the above answers, I also found this works:

```
class ExampleConstructor<T> {
  final Function _distance;

  ExampleConstructor(num this._distance(T a, T b)) 
}
```